# iOS GameKit: View GKChallenges issued by GKLocalPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

I am looking for a way to view `GKChallenges` issued by the `GKLocalPlayer`. I am able to load current challenges for the local player with `loadReceivedChallengesWithCompletionHandler:` but I cannot see challenges that were created by the local player and sent to other players.

I've been up and down the Apple docs but I can't seem to find any mention of this, does anyone have any experience with this?